# Get coordinations of the element

Tags: jquery

To get the coordinates of the mouse we use e.pageY and e.pageX. What about class or ID? It should look like:

`$(this).pageY;` or something similar? Is it even possible to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`position`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) or [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) depending on what you want. `position` will give you the element's position relative to the offset parent, and `offset` will give you the position relative to the document.

Answer (score 2):

The [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) method returns the position (top and left) of an element.

```
var offset = $("selector").offset();
offset.top   // Top position, relative to the top of the page
offset.left  // Left position, relative to the left of the page
```

Answer (score 2):

if you wan to get the coordinates of some element relative to the document i.e. the whole page representing the content, you can use `offset()` method. Otherwise if you want to get coordinates relative to the parent element you can use `position()` method. Both these functions return top and left of the element.

```
   var absolute_coordinates = $('#mydiv').offset(); // top and left with respect to document

   var relative_coordinates = $('#mydiv').position(); //top and left with respect to parent 

   alert('#mydiv is ' + relative_coordinates.top
          + 'px below from parent and absolute_coordinates.top + 
         'px below from document');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use offset

```
$(".divItem").click(function(){
    alert("Left is : "+$(this).offset().left)
});
```

Here is a sample : http://jsfiddle.net/ZBeWq/4/